# Best way to handle lists in cupboard (android library)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Cupboard (https://bitbucket.org/qbusict/cupboard) is a very convinient library, but unfortunately it does not support mapping lists to the database and lists need to be handled by hand. But what is the way to handle them?

Comment: I happen to be experimenting with it too and I can't even find anything functional to retrieve more than 1 object at a time. I'm considering to create a wrapper that holds all my objects just to deal with this or to switch to something else entirely.

Comment: Finally I stopped with using Gson and represent my lists as a json string.

Comment: And you store the json string instead? How do you retrieve data efficiently?

Comment: Yes, I store json strings that I create with Gson.toJson(Object) and then get string and convert it to object with Gson.fromJson(String, Class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can let Cupboard to the serializing for you by using a `FieldConverter`. I've recently released the [cupboard-tools](https://bitbucket.org/littlerobots/cupboard-tools) project that contains a `FieldConverter` that uses `Gson` to serialize and deserialize lists or other objects.

Answer (score 0):

Serializing lists into json and storing them as strings seems to be the best solution.